# Найти все числа, кратные q, которые взаимно просты с p и меньше p. на Pascal

Tags: математика, pascal

Код написал, но он не выводит результат

```
var i, p, q: integer;
begin
  readln(p);
  readln(q);
  while p <> q do 
  begin
    if p > q then 
      p := p - q
    else
      q := q - p;
  end;
  
  i := q;
  while i < p do 
  begin
    if q = 1 then 
      write(i, ' ');
    inc(i, q);
  end;
  
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: начни отсюда - [ask]

Comment: ваш код проверяет на взаимную простоту только числа `p` и `q`. А вот числа `{q*n: 2<n<floor(p/q)}` не проверяются. А ничего не выводит, скорее всего, потому что вы ввели не взаимно простые числа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
function gcd(a, b: integer): integer;
{ Calculates GCD using Euclidean algorithm. }
var 
    tmp: integer;
begin
    while b <> 0 do
    begin
        tmp := b;
        b := a mod b;
        a := tmp;
    end;
    gcd := a;
end;

var
    p, q, d: integer;
begin
    write('p: ');
    readln(p);
    write('q: ');
    readln(q); 
    // нет чисел, кратных q, но < p, если сам q > p
    if q > p then 
        halt;
    // если q и p не взаимно простые - нет чисел кратных q которые взаимно простые с p
    if gcd(p, q) <> 1 then 
        halt;
    writeln(q);
    for d := 2 to p div q do
    begin
        if gcd(p, d) = 1 then
            writeln(q * d);
    end;
end.
```

P.S. код можно немного оптимизировать, если цикл

```
for d := 2 to p div q do
    begin
        if gcd(p, d) = 1 then
            writeln(q * d);
    end;
```

Изменить так:

```
d := 2;
step := 1;
if p mod 2 = 0 then
begin
    d := 3;
    step := 2;
end;
while d < p div q do
begin
    if gcd(p, d) = 1 then
        writeln(q*d);
    d := d + step;
end;
```

Comment: в алгоритме евклида - деление с остатком, а не тормозное вычитание.  у евклида - логарифм, у вас - линейное время

Comment: @n1tr0xs почему при вводе 15 и 3 чего не выводит

Comment: а что должно вывести?

Comment: @ESkri спасибо за замечание, исправил.

Comment: @Lucifer04 давайте посмотрим на пары: (15,3) -> общий делитель 3; (15, 6) -> общий делитель 3; (15, 9) -> общий делитель 3; (15, 12) ->общие делители (3, 4). Всё, числа кончились

Comment: @n1tr0xs а как программа понимает кратность на q?

Comment: числа `q*d` всегда кратны `q`, если `q` и `d` - целочисленные.

Comment: @t1tr0xs можете объяснить этот код ```function nod(a, b: Integer): Integer;begin
  if b = 0 then    nod:= a
  else    nod:= nod(b, a mod b);
end;var
  i,q,p:integer;  begin
    read(q,p);    i:=q;
        while i < p do
    begin      if nod(i,p) = 1 then
        write(i,' ');     inc(i,q)
    end;  end.```

Comment: могу, но я не понимаю какое отношение он имеет к моему ответу.

Comment: @n1tr0xs этот код делает вроде бы  тоже самое и мне нужно узнать как узнается кратность q

Comment: ну у вас это делается через `inc(i, q)` - если мы к числу прибавим его же само - оно будет кратно изначальному, что почти то же самое, что и в моем коде. просто у вас - накопительное сложение. у меня - перебор множителей

Comment: `Lucifer04` кратность q можно узнать с помощью `x mod q`, но перебор **всех** чисел с проверкой каждого, кратно ли оно q и нод(x,p) - самый примитивный и долгий путь. Быстрее, как описано в ответе, работать только с числами вида q*d - заведомо кратными q